# Rename multiple variables with the same suffix in Stata

Tags: stata

How can I rename multiple variables with the ending _pagesubmit to remove that suffix? For example, the variables:

```
timer_climate_t1_pagesubmit
timer_climat_open_t1_pagesubmit
timer_covid_intro_t2_pagesubmit
```

should be renamed to:

```
timer_climate_t1
timer_climat_open_t1
timer_covid_intro_t2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rename *_pagesubmit *
```

See `help rename group` for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [renvarlab](http://www.haghish.com/statistics/stata-blog/stata-programming/download/renvarlab.html) which has a number of nice renaming features:

```
renvarlab timer_*_pagesubmit, postdrop(11)
```